# How to see changes happening with Storyboard when editing code file and vice versa?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, storyboard

When I compile my iOS/macOS application, Storyboard file and Swift files are combining, and I see the result in fully working application.

Is it possible to see the preview of application's appearance, where I'll see changes, applied in storyboard, and the changes, applied in code,  while writing the code or editing the Storyboard?

And is it possible to see changes, applied in storyboard (color, properties etc), in swift file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't fully understand how storyboards work and therefore have confused expectations.

Storyboard and Swift files are not combining during compilation.

What happens is that `UIViewController` uses Storyboard to initialise the view and all it's subviews and set all the properties. This initialisation happens during runtime. Probably you are thinking that it generates another Swift file that has the code to create all these view, which is not correct.

It also has connections to your IBOutlets and just assigns the references to your class in Swift, which later you can use, for example, to change colours programmatically.

There are a few ways of previewing different stuff in Xcode:

1. Xcode allows to preview views from Interface Builder using different devices and languages. Open the Assistant Editor (in the top bar, the icon with 2 circles), and then in the assistant editor select Preview. After that you can add multiple device resolutions, orientations and pick the language. However, it will just display the view from IB and doesn't run your Swift class which is connected to the view.
2. If you are making a custom view, then you can add `@IBDesignable` attribute and that will make Xcode compile the class for Interface Builder and run some parts of it to make it look like when you run it in your app. I could recommend this article about it - http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I appreciate that!